# Resize android application

Tags: android, resize, scale

I created app in android, everywhere looks great, but on the phone which has resolution 540 x 960 I have black background on the right side and bottom,

How can I resize this ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can get around this by setting your parent layout height and width to fill parent in all activities.

Or try this,

If you want uniform margin on all sides for all devices and screen sizes, then use marginRight, marginLeft, etc. in your xml and set 'x'dip where x is a number and dip is device independent pixel. This will give uniform margin for all devices, screen sizes and resolutions.